# Help on a custom razor HelperResult creation

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 project, I have created a PaginatedList helper. I handle this inside the view as follows;

```
@model TugberkUgurlu.Mvc.Helpers.PaginatedList<ContactModel>

@*
some razor code here to display the data
*@

<div id="pager">

    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {

        @:@Html.RouteLink("<<<< Previous",
                   "Default",
                    new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1) })

    }

    @if (Model.TotalPages >= 2)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.TotalPages; i++)
        {

            int value = i + 1;

            if (Model.PageIndex == i)
            {

                @:@Html.RouteLink(value.ToString(),
                   "Default",
                    new { page = (i) }, new { @class = "bold" })

            }
            else
            { 

                @:@Html.RouteLink(value.ToString(),
                   "Default",
                    new { page = (i) })

            }

        }
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {

        @:@Html.RouteLink("Next >>>>",
                   "Default",
                    new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })

    }

</div>
```

I would like to create a HelperResult for the code inside the `<div id="pager"></div>` element so that I won't be repeating myself and most of all, when I make a change to that code, it will be changed everywhere it is being used.

I haven't come up with the best idea yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For my use I realized an helper that do something similar to your request. I use some other variables, but I think you get the idea and can take my code and modify according to your need

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, int totalItems, int itemsPerPage, int currentPage, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
  return PageLinks(html, totalItems, itemsPerPage, currentPage, "", "", pageUrl);
}

public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, int totalItems, int itemsPerPage, int currentPage, string cssClass, string cssClassSelectedPage, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
  int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / itemsPerPage);
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
  {
    string css = cssClass;
    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
    tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
    tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
    if (i == currentPage)
      css += " " + cssClassSelectedPage;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
      tag.AddCssClass(css);
    result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
  }
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

Then from the view you make a call like this:

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.TotalItems, Model.PageSize, Model.Page, "page_link", "active_page", x => Url.Action("MyList", "Home", new { page = x }))%>
```

Basically I pass a function with a routing rule to generate all the links

This is my rule in Global.asax

```
      routes.MapRoute("", "MyList/{page}", new { controller = "Home", action = "MyList", page = 0 }, new { page = @"\d+" });
```

Hope it can help accomplish your task